# Salat - Why it creating two id fields

Tags: scala, akka, salat

**What I tried:**

I tried around one and half day, not resolved yet.

I tried by creating MyEntityTemp entity similar to MyEntity and written a converter. Even I am getting two id fields. Please need help to resolve.

I found some of MyEntity inherited classes have id field, so I removed that inherited classes even I am getting same problem.

```
case class MYEntity (
   @Key("_id") id: String =ObjectId(),
//  id: String,   // I tried like this also, even I am getting two ids
  regionId: String,
  zoneId: String)

object ObjectId {
  def apply(): String = new org.bson.types.ObjectId().toString
}
```

**Using:**
   **Scala 2.10.5**
   **Salat 1.9.9**
   **json4s-native 3.3.0**

**Error:**

Need to get like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "5411b214ebb290b62281c845",
}
```

But getting

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58f5eabb0c7443adcca88e57"),
    "id" : "5411b214ebb290b62281c845",
}
```

Could you please help me, why I am getting like this.

Comment: When you say "getting" do you mean in the Mongo record or in generated JSON. Is `object ObjectId` in your code? What is your motivation there?

Comment: not in JSON, I am seeing in mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I worked for two days on it and tried with multiple ways even getting same problem. Finally I tried to do with Casbah mongo api instead of Salat.

I build a MongoDBObject, I replaced with id field name with _id and saved in mongoDB. Now it happening what I expected.

Comment: Will wondering about this question and your answer. Did you understand that Mongo will assign an ID field having name _id of type "ObjectId" even if your case class does not have such a field?